# Powershell read from CSV set variables

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file with two columns "Path" and "Owner".

I've created the below script and it can read from the CSV file, but when I attempt to assign the variables from the csv it fails.

```
Import-Csv C:\test\output.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Path = $_.path
    $owner = $_.owner
    "The username is $Path and the owner is $owner"
}
ForEach-Object {
    $Path = $_.path
    $owner = $_.owner

    $Account = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList '$owner'
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Path
    $Acl.SetOwner($Account)

    Set-Acl -Path $owner -AclObject $Acl
}
```

The output is correct from the first segment and shows the path and the owner, but the second part doesn't set the owner according to the path.

Comment: The second foreach has no input object to iterate over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second foreach has no input object to iterate over. So either

- import to a variable and pipe it twice to the foreach loops
- import twice

---

```
$csv = import-csv c:\test\output.csv 
$csv | foreach-object {
  $Path = $_.path
  $owner =$_.owner
  "The username is $Path and the owner is $owner"
}
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Path = $_.path
    $owner =$_.owner
    $Account = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList "$owner"
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
    $Acl.SetOwner($Account);
    Set-Acl -Path $Path -AclObject $Acl
}
```

Comment: The issue now is it's not accepting the variables in $Acl.SetOwner($Account)                                 Exception calling "SetOwner" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."

Comment: Variables inside single quotes are not expanded, use double quotes instead (sorry didn't test this for the obvious previous mistake).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help with this.. I can't believe I made such schoolboy errors :)

Comment: the errors I am now getting is  Set-Acl -Path $owner -AclObject $Acl; Set-Acl : Cannot find path and the way I have the csv set up is Path Owner
C:\Users\Gin\Desktop\test\New folder Host\Nath
C:\Users\Gin\Desktop\test\New folder - Copy Host\Raj

Comment: $owner is not a path, change to $path. Maybe you should use `Test-Path` prior trying to change the ownership. I'd gracefully accept a vote up and/or a checked answer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks you so much for your help, saved me hours and spared the internet from a bashing :)

Answer (score 1):

1. When you use `ForEach-Object`, you need to return the current object for it to go through the pipe and into the next foreach. You can use `return` for this, or just type the current object variable (`$_`) at the end.
2. Since you are passing `$owner`, you don't need to enclose it with quotations. Just use the variable.
3. Don't use single quotations for variables because single quotations output the string with literal text you typed. So it's *literally* `$owner` and not value of `$owner` variable.

Code:

```
Import-Csv C:\test\output.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Path = $_.path
    $owner = $_.owner
    "The username is $Path and the owner is $owner"
    return $_ # Returning current object
}
ForEach-Object {
    $Path = $_.path
    $owner = $_.owner

    $Account = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList $owner # No quotations
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Path
    $Acl.SetOwner($Account)

    Set-Acl -Path $owner -AclObject $Acl
}
```

Also, you don't need 2 foreach loops. Why not just join them? You can use `Write-Host` to output the string you wanted.

```
Import-Csv C:\test\output.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $Path = $_.path
    $owner = $_.owner
    Write-Host "The username is $Path and the owner is $owner"

    $Account = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList $owner
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Path
    $Acl.SetOwner($Account)

    Set-Acl -Path $owner -AclObject $Acl
}
```